# Starting TensorFlow on Docker on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow

I followed the directions to install TensorFlow on Docker on Google Cloud here :

http://tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup.html#docker-based-installation

The first time, it did work and showed the tensorflow prompt.
Now that I have logged out and back in, I get this:

`technologiclee@docker-playground:~$ docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow
root@2e87064f0743:/#`

I also tried this:

`root@2e87064f0743:/# docker run b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow-full
bash: docker: command not found`

Is there a different way to start TensorFlow on Docker after it is installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `docker run -it` command brings up a bash shell in a container where TensorFlow is installed. Once you are at the `root@2e87064f0743:/#` prompt you can start an interactive TensorFlow session by starting `ipython` as the following example shows:

```
$ docker run -it b.gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow

root@2e87064f0743:/# ipython

Python 2.7.6 ...
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf
In [2]: c = tf.constant(5.0)
In [3]: sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
I tensorflow/core/...

In [4]: c.eval()
Out[4]: 5.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your time @mrry , this is what I did not know.