# Can I use TensorFlow in a Google App Engine module?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow, gae-module

I have a data processing module as part of my GAE application. TensorFlow has separate installers for Linux and OSX, which indicates to me that it might not play nicely with the GAE sandbox. Is it possible to use TensorFlow in a GAE module?

Comment: you can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33821449/starting-tensorflow-on-docker-on-google-cloud), although not sure if this is the thing you are looking for. But docker installation would be easier i think.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Yes. Updated Answer

From Nicholas's comment:

> It is actually possible in F4_1G instances, you have to specify tf-cpu library in requirements.txt: `tensorflow-cpu==2.8.0`

## No. Old, Obsolete Answer

No, you won't be able to install TensorFlow on standard instances.

You can, however, install whatever you like on [managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) instances. Though it may be easier to use compute engine instances instead.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is? - beyond the fact that Standard services are "sandboxed". What is it specifically about TensorFlow that isn't allowed in the Standard environment when compared to other libraries/dependencies?

Comment: TensorFlow is C++. The standard environment (at this time) only supports code written in Python, Java, Node.js, PHP, Ruby, and Go.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments

Comment: It is actually possible in F4_1G instances, you have to specify tf-cpu librairy in requirements.txt:
tensorflow-cpu==2.8.0